# "onecore" folder in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 RTM VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\lib folder, there is one folder called "onecore", inside there are folders for x64, x86 and arm, each containing some .lib files that already exist VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\lib{x64,x86,arm}. What is the function of these duplicates?

Also, what is the meaning of thus "onecore" anyway?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170814100651/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/what-s-new-in-windows There's a paragraph in there describing what OneCore is. Not sure the exact implications or when you'd want to deploy one over the other, but there you have it.

Answer (score 2):

*[OneCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-for-onecore)* is a Microsoft term for different targets like mobile, desktop and IoT. The libraries are intended to be used by C++ programs for those targets. E.g. heed that MFC and [C++ AMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx) are not part of OneCore.

The OneCore libraries are also part of the Visual Studio MSVC Redist folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are C++ runtimes for [Universal Windows Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) applications.