# VS2017 and missing "api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll" on Win7/XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp

After porting some of my programs from VS2015 to VS2017 in noticed that the binaries no longer run on Windows 7 or Windows XP - even though they *have* been compiled with `v141_xp` toolset. The program fails to start with missing DLL `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll` (note the **2**).

I'm well aware that those `api-ms-win-*` DLL's belong to the UCRT and that, starting with VS2015, I have to redistribute the UCRT DLL's from the Windows 10 SDK (to be found at `Redist\ucrt\DLLs` in the Windows 10 SDK directory), along with my application - just redistributing the `vcruntime140.dll` and `msvcp140.dll` is **not** sufficient. But there is only `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll` in my Windows SDK directory, but **not** `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll`. I just downloaded and re-installed the latest Windows SDK (10.0.15063), just to be sure. Still the DLL in question is absent!

I also tried installing the VS2017 Redistributable package on the Windows 7 (or XP) machine via `VC_redist.x86.exe` - latest version downloaded from Visual Studio web-site (14.11.25325). Obviously that copies the `api-ms-win-*` DLL's  into the "System32" directory. But, again, only `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll`, but **not** `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll`. App still won't start.

[image]

[image]

---

**[EDIT]**

This of course only applies if I link against the DLL runtime (`/MD`). If I link against the "static" runtime (`/MT`) I get a binary that has **no** DLL dependencies on UCRT and runs fine on Windows 7 and XP.

---

**[EDIT #2]**

Please refer to my other post (including EDIT) for the resolution of the mess:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773325/1766377

Comment: best is to create a extra project configuration for XP, install an older VS version in a VM and compile the xp project file via the older VS version.

Comment: I have already chosen the `v141_xp` toolset in my project configuration - which exists specifically to target Windows XP. In VS2015, using the `v140_xp` toolset works great to create binaries for Windows XP - as long as I redistribute `vcruntime140.dll` and `msvcp140.dll` as well as the `api-ms-win-*` UCRT DLL's from the Windows 10 SDK. But it appears that VS2017 now is linking against a newer UCRT version, for which the required redistributables are not (yet) available - neither in the Windows 10 SDK nor via the VS2017 redistributable installer - which seems like a bug to me...

Comment: I understand your issue. that's why use an older VS version to compile the XP exe

Comment: That I can use on older VS version (e.g. VS2015) to produce a binary that will work on Windows 7 or Windows XP is *not* the point here. The point is that - to the best of my knowledge - VS2017 is *supposed* to produce binaries that work on Windows 7 (and also on Windows XP when `v141'_xp` toolset is selected), but apparently fails to do so! Or, more specifically, it appears that M$ missed to provide the right redistributable DLL's for those platforms in its current Windows SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, this is quite interesting: *Just now* my VS2017 found a new update. Apparently that updated my VS2017 from **v15.2** to **v15.3.1**. The runtime libraries were updated as well, it seems!

There are now ***two*** directories, `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.11.25325` *and* `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.11.25415`, inside my VS2017 install directory. The **`vcruntime140.dll`** exists in both directories. But the *newer* version (25415, right) has quite different dependencies, compared to the older one (25325, left):

[image]

Only the "new" version has dependencies that are missing on Windows 7. So, I should be fine going with the "old" version. But it means I'm locked to the "old" version. Is this normal / intended ???

(BTW: Both DLL versions from VS2017 **v15.3.1** are *newer* than the one I originally took from **v15.2**)

---

**[EDIT]**

So, it was just brought to my attention that there is a ***subtle*** difference between the `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.11.25325` *and* `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.11.25415` directories: The 25415 directory has all DLL files inside another sub-folder called `onecore`, the other one doesn't. Apparently, this means that the "newer" DLL versions (the one with `onecore` sub-folder) are ***not*** supposed to be redistributed with normal Desktop applications; they are strictly for the "OneCore" Mobile/IoT platform.

*Conclusion:*
M$ did a great job to design the Redist directory structure ***as confusing as possible***. Putting the version numbers of the "normal" and the "onecore" redistributables on the same level of the directory hierarchy (rather than having separate `onecore` and `desktop` directories on ***that*** level) indicates that those directories represent different versions of the same thing - which isn't the case at all :-/

#### Do *not* redistribute any `*/onecore/*` DLL's with normal Desktop applications!

Answer (score 0):

In the property pages for the project, try changing the Windows SDK version from 10.0.15063.0 to 10.0.10240.0.  I think that will fix it, provided that the older SDK is installed on your build machine.  Something else to try is to change the platform toolset to v140_xp.  VS 2017 then builds with the VS 2015 tool chain, provided that VS 2015 is installed.

My personal preference is to avoid any 'DLL hell' by linking with the static runtime, although this won't work if an exe and a dll need to share a heap and incurs some space penalty if you are building several binaries (I just have two).

Comment: Do you mean the "Windows SDK Version" option on the "General" page? I already have set that to ***"7.0"***, which I think is required (and applied automatically!) for the `v141_xp` toolset. Also, as you can see in the *Dependency Walker* screenshot that I posted: The dependency to `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll` (note the **2**) originates from the ***VS2017*** incarnation of `VCRUNTIME140.DLL`. And *that* DLL won't change at all, regardless how I build my own executable, I think...

Comment: Ah, interesting, I missed that, sorry, how horrible, it should be called VCRUNTIME141.DLL should it not, and yes, that's what I meant.  I would think building with the v140_xp toolset and using the VS 2015 redistributables is your only option then, although you lose out on the latest compiler features that way.  What a mess.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on your new post so I will comment here.  Perhaps some kind moderator will move it.  Anyway, I don't think the two directories you mention are different 'vintages' of the redistributables package.  Version 14.11.25415 has everything in a 'onecore' folder and, since it is causing you so much trouble, is probably not the one you want, see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672650/oncore-folder-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Thanks! So it seems that the DLL's in `onecore` are for targeting the *unified* Desktiop/Mobile/IoT platform (aka "OneCore") and **not** what we should be redistributing for normal Desktop applications. I think the directory structure is quite confusing! They should have called it `Redist\desktop\<version>` and `Redist\onecore\<version>`, rather than putting the version number *first* - which implies that it's just two versions of the same thing - which it isn't. Could have saved my some headaches...

Comment: Something like that, it's all very unclear.  I still have VS 2017 15.2 and my two Redist folders are 14.10.25008 and 14.10.25017, the latter being onecore (only) and the former the opposite, but under the Tools folder (which leads to the include, lib and related folders) I have only 14.10.25017, with a onecore folder under lib.  Different Tools and Redist versions feels wrong but if the 'older' redistributables work then I guess it's OK. I would submit a bug report to Microsoft though.  Your original observation that a file appears to be missing from the (onecore) redistributables seems valid.